# Windows 8 is using DHCP but not getting a new address

Tags: windows, networking, wireless-networking, windows-8, virtualbox

In the properties window of both IPv4 and IPv6 (accessed from `Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network Connections`), "Obtain an IP address automatically" are selected, but `ipconfig` shows the IPv4 address is not changing from `192.168.1.137`. I used to have an Ubuntu VM that used a static IP set to `192.168.1.137`, but it was deleted a long time ago. None of my other VMs have a static IP. The IPv4 property for the VirtualBox Host-Only Network in `Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network Connections` is set to use `192.168.56.1` as its IP, which I believe was set when VirtualBox was installed.

Running the commands `ipconfig /release` and `ipconfig /renew` don't change the IP address. Rebooting certainly doesn't (this has been my situation for months).

**Is there any way to track down what is forcing my windows machine to have the same IP?**

Changing this machine's configuration to use a static IP does solve the problem, but it seems hacky and I would still like to know what is causing this.

If needed, `ipconfig` output:

```
Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : nelson-pc
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . : 
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No

Ethernet adapter Ethernet:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Killer e2200 Gigabit Ethernet Controller
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 4C-CC-6A-25-AA-9C
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 2:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 1A-1C-A2-01-F8-99
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Qualcomm Atheros AR938x Wireless Network Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 68-1C-A2-01-F8-99
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::9dbb:2386:1ff4:cdae%3(Preferred) 
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.137(Preferred) 
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Monday, August 14, 2017 11:22:13 PM
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Wednesday, August 16, 2017 2:53:41 AM
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 57154722
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-1F-7E-3C-FE-68-1C-A2-01-F8-99
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Ethernet adapter VirtualBox Host-Only Network:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 0A-00-27-00-00-09
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::4cfa:94e7:9eed:226d%9(Preferred) 
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.56.1(Preferred) 
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 151650343
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-1F-7E-3C-FE-68-1C-A2-01-F8-99
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : fec0:0:0:ffff::1%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::2%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::3%1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Tunnel adapter isatap.{D2F31E5B-5B96-4C1A-806A-CB0E0DFCCC96}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter isatap.{BAF8AF36-13DB-406D-8E65-794EABC051DE}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #2
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
```

Comment: What is actually the problem? You're just getting that IP from your router. If the lease is refreshed often enough it won't expire so you will keep it.

Comment: @Seth For months? I thought the lease would be renewed far before that.

Comment: How many devices are actually connected? What does your DHCP configuration look like? Atfer all it can influence how your leases are handled. Leases can be anything from minutes to months. Usual default values for Windows are 1 hour/1 day (depending on version). If you do have a lease `ipconfig /all` should include information about the duration.

Comment: @Seth the `ipconfig` output has been replaced with `ipconfig \all` output

Comment: @Seth The `192.168.1.1` page (what do you call that? the router config page?) says there are 18 devices connected. Other than showing `ipconfig \all` as you said, I don't know how to show you my DHCP config

Comment: look in the DHCP settings of your router which lease time you have configured.

Comment: @magicandre1981 After digging through my router’s config page and google, I believe it is hard-coded in my router’s firmware and cannot be changed from the standard 24/48 hours or whatever it is. A forum also mentioned the lease obtained time and lease expiration date is shown with `ipconfig /all` output. Under the `Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi` section: `Lease Obtained: Monday, August 14...` and `Lease Expires: Wednesday, August 16...`.

Comment: Even with all that information I'm kind of wondering what your actual question is. Did you just want to figure out why you did get the same IP repeatedly? If so the answer is that the lease is being renewed every so often. Depending on how your configuration looks and how many devices you got on the network it might also happen to be the first free IP.

Comment: @Seth That is exactly my question. I want to use that IP for my raspberry pi, but while my PC has it, there is a conflict. What would keep renewing the lease? I usually keep my PC running most of the time, but it was off for about a week at one point. The number of devices connected to my home network remains fairly constant. Most of those devices are running 24/7, and the only IP addresses whose 4th octet goes above 20 are static. Is my best option here just to set a static IP for my PC and just move on?

Comment: Why does it have to be that IP? With DHCP you should expect IP changes at any time. If you want to use a specific IP for a specific devices either your router has to support some reservation mechanism (based on MAC) or you would need to use a static IP. If you don't have any configuration options available for your DHCP server using static IPs might be a good idea.

Comment: @Seth For consistency, mainly. So I don’t have to change other things. That’s what I plan on doing: I want to set `192.168.1.137` as the static IP for my Raspberry Pi, but I can’t until my PC stops using it. I meant should I just set a static IP, other than that one, for my PC because DHCP isn’t giving my PC a new address.

Comment: in the router options set the IP range to use 192.168.1.101-254 as range and assign IPs from range 192.168.1.2-99 manually to avoid IP conflicts

Answer (score 0):

While doing something else on my router's config page, I stumbled upon the `Address Reservation` section with an entry for my PC with the IP address in question. I deleted the entry and will accept this answer if my IP ever changes on its own.